# Should my bachelor's degree match the graduate program that I am trying to get into?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters

I am an Italian undergraduate student of natural sciences, I would like to pursue a graduate program in the USA like a PhD or a MSc. Should I change my major in order to match the graduate program I will try to get into in order to improve my chances?

The graduate programs that interest me in order of liking, are:

- Computer Science & Entrepreneurship (or other innovative programs with a scientific and entrepreneurial component);
- Computer Science;
- Oceanography/Marine biology;
- Computational mathematics;

Comment: There is no universal answer -- you'll need to say specifically what fields are involved.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than providing you with my opinion (I think you're aspirations are realistic), I think you should contact the admissions and academic advisers of your chosen post-graduate institution and ask them.

Ask them about your proposed course of graduate studies.

Ask them about how much course work you may need in order to "catch up" to other students planning to enter that major field of study.

I *believe* most institutions will allow you to start your post-graduate studies while you're still taking any undergraduate classes you may need.  The only way to know for sure is talk to someone at the University.